# Changed icon is only static when switching file views

Tags: nautilus, icons

I got a question about changing icons in my home folder.

Say I have a new folder called Resources and I want to assign one of the matching folder icons available in /usr/share/icons/Adwaita. I have to select the pixel size because it separates them in folder like 256x256, 48x48, etc... Once, I select the right size and it all matches up and looks good, if I feel like switching view modes from say icon to list, all the other folder icons adjust to that size besides the custom one I set because it is only set to that one size.

Anyone know a simple solution to change icons that adjust accordingly to view?